# Alegreya SC in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, packages, fontspec, displaystyle

Does anyone know how to use the font Alegreya SC in LaTeX?

[image]

I am aware of the package `Alegreya`, but it does not seem to provide the right capitalization. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing fonts should be done with care.

Looking in `Alegreya.sty` is not easy, because of the many options. So we can ask LaTeX to do the work for us.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

{\scshape\xdef\fontparams{\expandafter\string\the\font}}
\texttt{\fontparams}

\end{document}
```

Don't worry about the mysterious sequence of commands, but just for information

- `\the\font` expands to the internal command for the current font
- we need to “stringify” it so we can print it, but `\string` must be applied after expanding `\the\font`, so `\expandafter` does the trick
- `\xdef` full expands the given replacement text and globally defines the macro
- with `\texttt` we print it in a reasonable way for reading

The result is

[image]

OK, now we have the needed ingredients.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\alegreyasc}{%
  \usefont{\encodingdefault}{Alegreya-LF}{regular}{sc}%
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textalegreyasc}{\alegreyasc}

\begin{document}

Words in \textalegreyasc{Alegreya Small Caps 123}

\end{document}
```

I define both the switch `\alegreyasc` and the text command. Choose other names, if you so prefer.

[image]

If in the file to get the font parameters you do `\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}`, you'll get

[image]

With

```
\newcommand{\alegreyasc}{%
  \usefont{\encodingdefault}{Alegreya-OsF}{regular}{sc}%
}
```

the example text above would become

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer really, just add `\textsc{Abc}`.

Comment: `\sc` is not defined by default in latex, use `{\scshape Abc}` or `\textsc{Abc}`

Comment: Thank you, by any chance do you know how to apply it on a specific sentence? `\usepackage{Alegreya}` changes the font of the entire document

Comment: just use `\fontfamily{...}\selectfont` the details of `...` depend on which tex engine you are using, see the package