# Alegreya SmallCaps work in LaTeX and XeLaTeX, but not LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, small-caps

Using a full, updated install of TeXLive 2022 (on Mac OS 13.1 with TeXmaker), the following MWE compiles correctly with LaTeX and XeLaTeX, but somehow the small caps do not work when using LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

Test!

\textsc{testing with small caps!}

\end{document}
```

Note that the same problem occurs with the sans font (when using `\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}`).

[Alegreya SC in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667015/61215) presents a possible workaround, but is it possible to make the typical `\textsc{}` solution workable?

Is it a problem with my TeXmaker settings?

[image]

Comment: I get small caps.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, this helps diagnose. It's a November install, so I'll try updating it and seeing what changes.

Comment: You could try `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Alegreya}[SmallCapsFont={* SC},ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont={Alegreya SC Italic}}]`

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately an update (including an update on the `alegreya` package!) still leaves me with the same problem.